# Get previous X days of revenue for each group

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, where-clause

Here is my table

```
CREATE TABLE financials ( 
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
CountryID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
ProductID VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,  
Revenue INT NOT NULL, 
cost INT NOT NULL, 
reg_date TIMESTAMP 
); 


INSERT INTO `financials` (`id`, `CountryID`, `ProductID`, `Revenue`, `cost`, `reg_date`) VALUES 
( 1, 'Canada', 'Doe'   , 20,  5, '2010-01-31 12:01:01'), 
( 2, 'USA'   , 'Tyson' , 40, 15, '2010-02-14 12:01:01'), 
( 3, 'France', 'Keaton', 80, 25, '2010-03-25 12:01:01'),
( 4, 'France', 'Keaton',180, 45, '2010-04-24 12:01:01'),
( 5, 'France', 'Keaton', 30,  6, '2010-04-25 12:01:01'),
( 6, 'France', 'Emma'  , 15,  2, '2010-01-24 12:01:01'),
( 7, 'France', 'Emma'  , 60, 36, '2010-01-25 12:01:01'),
( 8, 'France', 'Lammy' ,130, 26, '2010-04-25 12:01:01'),
( 9, 'France', 'Louis' ,350, 12, '2010-04-25 12:01:01'), 
(10, 'France', 'Dennis',100,200, '2010-04-25 12:01:01'),
(11, 'USA'   , 'Zooey' , 70, 16, '2010-04-25 12:01:01'),
(12, 'France', 'Alex'  ,  2, 16, '2010-04-25 12:01:01');
```

For each product and date combination, I need to get the revenue for previous 5 days. For instance, for Product ‘Keaton’, the last purchase was on 2010-04-25, it will only sum up revenue between 2010-04-20 to 2010-04-25 and therefore it will be 210. While for "Emma", it would return 75, since it would sum everything between 2010-01-20 to 2010-01-25.

```
SELECT ProductID, sum(revenue), reg_date
  FROM financials f
Where reg_date in (
    SELECT reg_date
    FROM financials as t2
    WHERE t2.ProductID = f.productID
    ORDER BY reg_date
    LIMIT 5)
```

Unfortunately, when i use either https://sqltest.net/ or http://sqlfiddle.com/ it says that 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery' is not supported. Would my query work or not?

Comment: I changed the data type of cost and revenue because... well it's obvious, isn't it? Anyway, please provide the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Your query is on the right track, but probably won't work in MySQL.  MySQL has limitations on the use of `in` and `limit` with subqueries.

Instead:

```
SELECT f.ProductID, SUM(f.revenue)
FROM financials f JOIN
     (SELECT ProductId, MAX(reg_date) as max_reg_date
      FROM financials
      GROUP BY ProductId
     ) ff
     ON f.ProductId = ff.ProductId and
        f.reg_date >= ff.max_reg_date - interval 5 day
GROUP BY f.ProductId;
```

EDIT:

If you want this for each product and date combination, then you can use a self join or correlated subquery:

```
SELECT f.*,
       (SELECT SUM(f2.revenue)
        FROM financials f2
        WHERE f2.ProductId = f.ProductId AND
              f2.reg_date <= f.reg_date AND
              f2.reg_date >= f.reg_date - interval 5 day
       ) as sum_five_preceding_days
FROM financials f;
```

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Thank you for pointing that out.  I edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some trials I ended up with some complex query, that I think it solves your problem

```
SELECT
  financials.ProductID, sum(financials.Revenue) as Revenues
FROM
  financials 
INNER JOIN (
      SELECT ProductId, GROUP_CONCAT(id ORDER BY reg_date DESC) groupedIds
      FROM financials
      group by ProductId
) group_max
  ON financials.ProductId = group_max.ProductId
     AND FIND_IN_SET(financials.id, groupedIds) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
group by financials.ProductID
```

First I used `group by financials.ProductID` to count revenues by products. The real problem you are facing is eliminating all rows that are not in the top 5, for each group. For that I used the [solution from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group), GROUP_CONCAT and FIND_IN_SET, to get the top 5 result without LIMIT. Instead of `WHERE IN` I used `JOIN` but with this, `WHERE IN` might also work.

Heres the [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2751f/23)

Comment: I will go with your query, but just out morbid curiousity, would my query have worked?

Comment: @eddd83 I think you are missing a group by, or more, other than that if it were supported would have been a correct way to approach this problem

Comment: @eddd83 . . . This takes the previous five days in the data, not the five calendar days up to the maximum date.